# Adding link to HTML image with animated background over top

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

I have this html to create an image which, when hovered over displays the text in the content/tagline divs:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="albums/Armed Forces Day 2022.html" class="link-tag" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></a>
    <img src="src/img/albums/Armed Forces Day 2022/RAF Falcons underneath parachute canopy.JPG"></img>
    <div class="content fade">Armed Forces Day Scarborough 2022</div>
    <div class="tagline fade">2022</div>
</div>
```

I have this CSS in order to animate the overlay on the image:

```
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-wrapper > img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.img-wrapper > .content {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family:'Bebas Kai', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: rgba(41, 41, 41, .8);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.img-wrapper > .tagline {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family:'Bebas Kai', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #999999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.img-wrapper > img,
.img-wrapper > .content,
.img-wrapper > .tagline {
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.img-wrapper > .content.fade,
.img-wrapper > .tagline.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}

.img-wrapper:hover > .content.fade,
.img-wrapper:hover > .tagline.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The aim is when the image is clicked, it links to another html page on my portfolio. I've attempted to put the link in the div, on the image, and in a separate div which contains the content & tagline, however it doesn't work on the webpage.

Comment: Make the link the wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want the image to be inside the link (inside the `<a>` element)

I think you should use a markup more like this:

```html
<a href="albums/Armed Forces Day 2022.html" class="link">
    <img src="src/img/albums/Armed Forces Day 2022/RAF Falcons underneath parachute canopy.JPG"" class="link__image" />
    <div class="content fade">Armed Forces Day Scarborough 2022</div>
    <div class="tagline fade">2022</div>
</a>
```

I made you here an example of what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/bvjows06/

This would allow you to click on any of the elements inside the `<a>`.
You would need to change the css to change the content and the tagline when you hover the `.image-link`, but i think that is something you can do on your own!

Just a side note: maybe you should rethink you file names (and links) so you don't have any spaces between the words, which can cause you some problems (ex: `armedForcesDay2022.html` instead of `Armed Forces Day 2022.html`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I keep the original img-wrapper diff, and wrap the link tag you provided around that, it works flawlessly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks once again for your help, and I've marked your answer as the accepted answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. You just had to wrap the whole `section` with the **anchor** tag.

```css
.img-wrapper {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}


.img-wrapper>img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.img-wrapper>.content {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: 'Bebas Kai', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: rgba(41, 41, 41, .8);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.img-wrapper>.tagline {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Bebas Kai', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #999999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.img-wrapper>img,
.img-wrapper>.content,
.img-wrapper>.tagline {
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.img-wrapper>.content.fade,
.img-wrapper>.tagline.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}

.img-wrapper:hover>.content.fade,
.img-wrapper:hover>.tagline.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="albums/Armed Forces Day 2022.html" class="link-tag"
        style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="img-wrapper">

            <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1658495679082-a88dc0818e4a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1632&q=80"></img>
            <div class="content fade">Armed Forces Day Scarborough 2022</div>
            <div class="tagline fade">2022</div>
        </div>
        </section>
    </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The CSS is a bit off, but if I just wrap the link tag around the img-wrapper diff, with no styling it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LukeDunkley no problem! If you think that it will help others in the fututre, accept my answer by clicking on the checked icon beside it. Cheers!